# How to access a variable that I only need to create once on Application.Start

Tags: c#, azure, caching, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

According to this guide:
https://github.com/mspnp/azure-guidance/blob/master/Retry-Service-Specific.md

They say:

Note that the StackExchange.Redis client uses multiplexing through a single connection. The recommended usage is to create an instance of the client **at application startup** and use this instance for all operations against the cache. For this reason, the connection to the cache is made only once, and so all of the guidance in this section is related to the retry policy for this initial connection—and not for each operation that accesses the cache.

Right now I have something like this:

```
public static Models.UserProfile GetUserProfile(string identityname)
        {
            /// It needs to be cached for every user because every user can have different modules enabled.
            try
            {
                var cachekeyname = "UserProfileInformation|" + identityname;
                IDatabase cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
                Models.UserProfile userProfile = new Models.UserProfile();
                object obj = cache.Get(cachekeyname);
```

I can move the connection line to global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {

            IDatabase cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();

        }
```

If I move that line, then how can I get that instance on the other methods where I need to use it?

this is the cache connection helper

```
public class CacheConnectionHelper
    {
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(SettingsHelper.AzureRedisCache);
        });

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it static inside the global.asax file

```
public class Global : HttpApplication {
    public static IDatabase Cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }
    .....
}
```

Now you can access the database object in any class by simply accessing `Global.Cache` which is your single instance of the database.